# How to change driver between amqp and db

Tags: database, xml

We have an extension that can make use of either MySQL driver `db` or RabbitMQ `amqp`. 
The drive is mentioned on these files:

```
etc/queue_consumer.xml
etc/queue_publisher.xml
etc/queue_topology.xml
```

https://github.com/Nosto/nosto-magento2/blob/develop/etc/queue_consumer.xml

https://github.com/Nosto/nosto-magento2/blob/develop/etc/queue_publisher.xml

https://github.com/Nosto/nosto-magento2/blob/develop/etc/queue_topology.xml

By default, the XML definition causes it use the `db`(MySQL). In order to switch over to RabbitMQ, all of the three XML files cited above need to be manually edited to set connection to `amqp`. Having done that, you need to run `setup:upgrade`. 
We cannot ship with the default being `amqp` as RabbitMQ isn't enabled by default in all Magento installations.

What is the recommended way - using overrides or the CLI - to force a queue to use the `amqp`? While it is possible to do this manually by editing extension sources, it seems to be an anti-pattern of editing sources directly. 
Does anybody have another idea? I appreciate the help!